# In TypeScript, is there a way to restrict extra/excess properties for a Partial<T> type when the type is a parameter to a function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript3.0

Is there a standard way to get Scenario 1 to have a compile error for not specifying known properties, just like in Scenario 2? Or is there some workaround?

```
class Class2 {
  g: number;
}

class Testing {
  static testIt3<T>(val: Partial<T>): void {
  }
}

const test = {
  g: 6,
  a: '6',
};

// Scenario 1
Testing.testIt3<Class2>(test);
// TS does not show any errors for this scenario

// Scenario 2
Testing.testIt3<Class2>({
  g: 6,
  a: '6',
});
// but it does for this scenario:
// Object literal may only specify known properties...
```

[Live code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-partial-type-issue)

Comment: I don't think there's any way around this; TypeScript doesn't have [exact types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936), and [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) only apply to object literals like in your Scenario 2.  If you need to manually specify `T` then you need something like [partial type parameter inference](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) to do what you're looking for, which also isn't supported.

Comment: If you're okay with [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) you could do something like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEDC5QEzQN4ChqegcwFzQDsBXAWwCMBTAJwG40BfNUSGAFQogBcBLA7VDFi5gewaJw6cAkpwDMAHlYA+ABQBKfPICq0CgA8JBACYwU0ANoBpaL2gBrCgE8A9gDNoWgLr5r+wyfsnN2hWaAB+EKtPaHwCCgA3amh6JWgVeLAQfC01aABeVPjnbiMBLHLoKgpOIioCNNyC1GTBTEZGJmcCLnFJfLKsPGgANgAaVugwfAByYenx+jo0di5ebAA6CS4ZBXgWRFU1FS3ONSWAenPoAGVgCgIwKm5naERlyTXNyR35PaRDlTocpDMYTKbQWbzBhnNBAA), I guess.  Let me know if you want me to write that up as an answer.

Comment: @jcalz yeah i just found [this github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31872) that kind of explains it

Comment: @jcalz So that type has to be defined in-line in the function you declared in ur example?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  My example depends on having two generic types: the `T` type which you manually specify as `Class2` (otherwise it's impossible to forbid anything, since any object will be `Partial<T>` for *some* `T`); and the `U` type which is inferred based on the type of `val`.  The generic constraint, `U extends { [K in keyof U]: K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never }` explicitly enforces that all properties of `val` need to come from the `T` type and can't be extra.  If that meets your needs I'm happy to write it up.

Comment: @jcalz Sry, I don't think I worded my question very well. I was just trying to figure out if there was a way to write that similarly, but without having to make multiple function calls. So I was trying to ask if I could abstract that `U extends...` out to a type declared above the function instead of as an inline generic parameter of a return function as you showed.

Comment: No, it needs to be generic in `U` so you can't move `U` out.  If anything you could make it a single function by hard-coding `T` as `Class2`.

Comment: @jcalz So in my actual project, I'm trying to infer the types based on a type passed in, so I was messing around with that using your link as a starting point. I think I may have found another way to do it.

Comment: See [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=17&ssc=21&pln=17&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEDC5QEzQN4ChqegcwFzQDsBXAWwCMBTAJwG4MsBPfY86ugXzTQoA8AHAPZUALtACWBYdQBmYYBWgAVBnwoAeRQD5ovKQQAmMAGJECwYWIEFU9TAQoB3aAAoAdO7BVsEfGAIMAbQBdAEp8RQ4uUEgYRQoICwJsGyxoBLALYGgpBIBJYQAWDQAaaABVHR49Q1RoAIBpcWsAawoGAWlyoPxG3QoDGFb2zsVoAH4lBqDoZgoAN2podk1nObAQAEZwlXUtUrWQfDKw6DmBMX0UrE5ONGArBOz40QBeK8w8aAA2YttoAHp-tAmNBTPoKNIJBR9L9UmB8AByL4I37sOhoOIJCTYVw5YT5ArOeAxRClPEhOhAA)

Comment: @jcalz It seems like my link gives the same error message, but is there a reason I should prefer the strategy in your example over the one I just linked in my previous comment?

Comment: In your example the value `Class2` passed in is not being used, so it's a dummy value whose only purpose is to help the compiler assign types.  I usually call this "dummying" and it's another workaround for partial type parameter inference (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57333791/2887218)).  Both of them have runtime effect.  If you're going to actually use the passed-in `Class2` constructor in the function implementation, then of course you should use this instead of currying, because the value is no longer a dummy value.  I will write this up as an answer soon.

Comment: @jcalz yes, in my actual project, that value passed in will be used. But I see your point, that if that's not the case, then it's probably better to use currying to avoid have to declare multiple type parameters on the function call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type system isn't geared toward such restrictions on extra object keys.  Types in TypeScript are not *exact* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936): if an object is of type `A`, and you add more properties to it that are not mentioned in the definition of `A`, the object is still of type `A`.  This is essentially required to support class inheritance where subclasses can add properties to superclasses.

The only time the compiler treats types as exact is when you are using a "fresh" object literal (that is, one that hasn't been assigned to anything yet) and passing it to something that expects an object type.  This is called [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks) and it is sort of a workaround for the lack of exact types in the language.  You want excess property checking to occur with "non-fresh" objects like `test`, but that won't happen.

TypeScript has no concrete representation for exact types; you can't take a type `T` and produce `Exact<T>` from it.  But you can use a [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) to get this effect.  Given a type `T`, and an object of type `U` that you want to conform to the unrepresentable `Exact<T>` type, you can make this:

```
type Exactly<T, U extends T> = {[K in keyof U]: K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never};
type IsExactly<T, U extends T> = U extends Exactly<T, U> ? true : false;

const testGood = {
    g: 1
}
type TestGood = IsExactly<Class2, typeof testGood>; // true

const testBad = {
    g: 6,
    a: '6',
};
type TestBad = IsExactly<Class2, typeof testBad>; // false
```

So the compiler is able to tell that `typeof testGood` is "`Exactly<Class2, typeof testGood>`" while `typeof testBad` is not `Exactly<Class2, typeof testBad>`.  We can use this to build a generic function to do what you want.  (In your case you want something like `ExactlyPartial<T, U>` instead of `Exactly<T, U>`, but it's very similar... just don't constrain `U` to extend `T`).

---

Unfortunately, your function is already generic in `T`, the type to make exact. And you are manually *specifying* `T`, the generic function needs to *infer* the type of `U`.  TypeScript doesn't allow *partial type argument inference* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242).  You have to either manually specify all type parameters in a function, or you have to let the compiler infer all type parameters in a function.  So there are workarounds:

One is to split your function in to a [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) function in which the first generic function lets you specify `T` and the returned generic function infers `U`.  It looks like this:

```
    class Testing {
        static testIt<T>(): <U extends { [K in keyof U]:
            K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never
        }> (val: U) => void {
            return () => { }
        }
    }

    Testing.testIt<Class2>()(testBad); // error, prop "a" incompatible
    Testing.testIt<Class2>()(testGood); // okay
```

This works as you expect, but has runtime impact in that you have to call a curried function for no reason at runtime.

Another workaround is to pass a value from which `T` can be inferred to the function.  Since you don't need such a value, this is essentially a dummy parameter.  Again, it has a runtime impact in that you have to pass in a value that is not used.  (You mentioned that you might actually be using such a value at runtime, in which case, this is no longer a workaround but the suggested solution, since you need to pass in something anyway, and the manual specification of `T` in your code example was a red herring.)  It looks like this:

```
    class Testing {
        static testIt<T, U extends { [K in keyof U]:
            K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never
        }>(ctor: new (...args: any) => T, val: U) {
            // not using ctor in here, so this is a dummy value                        
        }
    }

    Testing.testIt(Class2, testBad); // error, prop "a" incompatible
    Testing.testIt(Class2, testGood); // okay
```

The third workaround I can think of is to just use the type system to represent the result of the curried function return without actually calling it.  It has no runtime impact at all, which makes it more amenable to giving types to existing JS code, but it's a bit clunky to use since you have to assert that `Testing.testIt` acts the right way.  It looks like this:

```
    interface TestIt<T> {
        <U extends { [K in keyof U]: K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never }>(val: U): void;
    }

    class Testing {
        static testIt(val: object) {
            // not using ctor in here, so this is a dummy value                        
        }
    }
        
    (Testing.testIt as TestIt<Class2>)(testBad); // error, prop "a" incompatible
    (Testing.testIt as TestIt<Class2>)(testGood); // okay
```

---

Okay, hope one of those works for you.

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEDC5QEzQN4ChqegcwFzQDsBXAWwCMBTAJ2gF5oBGRAZgG40BfNNAFwE8ADhWgBRAB5hgPEHwA8AFQA00AKrQKYnhQIATGPIB8dVNADaAaWgBLAtADWFPgHsAZqoC6+Sxq26YD5zd5aAB+aHkLd2h8AgoAN2poDnZ+IWgASQhxSWk5JVV1TW09cKN6NR9imGypGQVlFSMwnioiYXwXMBAICnY0YCcCCB5oLWGAcScnHWN0LBx8Bk5eQWF5CgmpmfpMmtzZeEgIRGVUildRjZ5J6YNWaAB6B9HWim4nwictUYALMBGAO4-KwgYRja5bawkASgkjaHgwHg-YSHJDWAhaKidYAURRoD5WEZWGAEL7QMC2GzDCk46AXVHHZQQJzQSjQYBgKgUFxEEDcAZDEbggBCYG2qAwWDw0AAbHj5mB8AByGVKvHJFZpdbDUXi3YSWpyBknUarC4isV3R7PTrdN7cNAEMBwiACSQoohUKh8GzYCXzUBHcJXX3++ZYak8KzAS7DdI8BQGAAUAEp8LIKkU-CYLOj7I4LipPJLw+HvFmSgELsEwhFzFEYvFqCXwxwjEm4l18CoU3QjHEnFYZnNS+GuTxPbZU32TFxR0kW1wW9qowRsAA6cHxg4IY7JlNJi06FP3D7UKhOKjKAQXgTQABEYHv6IG0P+VjIoOXIbXm6u2+NfdDyuG5j1PZ4nDsMA+GWR1nQ2N1aQAEVIEgfTXMNMEDKBg2GUMR1LSNo1jHht3yTNfBKFAzEsGx80CDxcBbedy0o-wCyCUJwkiaJCCbKhmKwNskykS9GwBaAk3XaTOWwCB8ApPhe1oIx8k7EBu17Aj52tT4RiICBQ1Emg6ORLkmRZJFiWsGAwGgHRUL4aB1LaHS3PDQTMDnITuHmFdfT-OMeCTY1TiuXUT1089L2vW8HyfF8nDfKNPzePyfw3LdgtCkjQMij5IOg2CnRdRDhAAQSgahVz9dAWxsTFsTWf8E0MTDwwzQo2JzWjbCrNwiy8Lqqno6suLrBs+ISGhhPUzT8AHId2HmJcA13XCava+YiJjLKOy7OkyAAKwoKQtM88MPlJfTDIw4y8zM3FoGZX5rOsuyHJINDnK6Vz3P+i7vK83ysCTfzfyy8l9BancjkQAwDyPfLnmiq9oBvJw70fZ8bFfN0Uq-eYwYywLSJGSANoA3d4cRkCtmRukoJgjggA)

Comment: Yes, I simply was declaring the type instead of passing it in as the first argument in my initial example, because I thought it would be a more minimal example to show the issue I had. I hadn't considered that it may impact how best to design the function.