# How to access the type of object's value by its key?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

So I have a function that returns a function. I want to have this:

`fn: <T extends Object>(key: keyof T) => (value: ???) => void`

What I want for `???` to be the type of `instanceOfT[key]`. For example, if `T={name: string; age: number}` I want `fn('name')` to return `(value: string) => void` and for `fn('age')` to return `(value: number) => void`

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to partially infer generic type of your function. See GitHub issues:

- [Allow skipping some generics when calling a function with multiple generics #10571](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10571)
- [Proposal: Partial Type Argument Inference #26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242)
- [Problem with generic default values #37073](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37073)

You need to use one of workarounds:

- Curry
- Pass a dummy parameter
- Specify all parameters as generic arguments

See answer to [In TypeScript is it possible to infer string literal types for Discriminated Unions from input type of string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57325035/in-typescript-is-it-possible-to-infer-string-literal-types-for-discriminated-uni/)

```
namespace Curry {
  type Consumer<K> = (value: K) => void;

  function makeConsumer<P>()/*: <K extends keyof P>(key: K) => Consumer<P[K]>*/ { 
    function factory<K extends keyof P>(key: K): Consumer<P[K]> {
      return (value: P[K]) => console.log(value);
    }
    return factory;
  }
  const barConsumer = makeConsumer<{ bar: string }>()("bar");
}


namespace Dummy {
  type Consumer<K> = (value: K) => void;

  function makeConsumer<P, K extends keyof P>(dummy: P, key: K): Consumer<P[K]> { 
    return (value: P[K]) => console.log(value);  
  }
  type T = { bar: string };
  const barConsumer = makeConsumer(null! as T, 'bar');
}


namespace AllParamsInGeneric {
  type Consumer<K> = (value: K) => void;

  function makeConsumer<P, K extends keyof P>(): Consumer<P[K]> { 
    return (value: P[K]) => console.log(value);  
  }
  const barConsumer = makeConsumer<{ bar: string }, 'bar'>();
}
```